# Using toastr with MVC - how to pass state along during postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, toastr

I have an MVC view that allows a user to save a project they are working on. It also allows them to edit that project and post the edits as well. I want to setup a toastr (growler) notification so they can see that something has been done.

However, there is no "state" (for lack of a clear term). When the user clicks Save that posts to my controller which persists to the db and then calls RedirectToAction with the id of the saved project. that redirect goes to a details page that shows the user the properties of the project.

that details page is the same one that a user would get to if they are just viewing the project. So 1) i need to detect when i want to growl and 2) i need a way to persist the growl message from the controller back out to the details page.

If the growl message were a field in the db this would be no issue but that is silly. I also do not want to use TempData (right now it crashes because i have not setup caching for it).

Is there a way I can include the growl in the RedirectToAction and have the details page pick it up? Or will that be included in the url?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use TempData, you can use **Session State** directly.

*TempData uses Session State under to hood.*

Only drawback is you will have to clear Session value once the value is retrieved; it is not the case in TempData.